# How do I mine VoteCoin?

Tags: altcoin, gpu-mining, mining-software, cpu-mining, investing

First I am not trying to open a bank but I have a core i3 3210 @ 3.20 GHz and a gt 210(pretty bad).I know I am late at mining so I thought of alt coins,like people who invested in bitcoin first, now they would have returned with a greater result.I bet you gotta agree with me like some more coins Monero,Zcash,Etherium,Dash.

These coins were also worth nothing as the time went by, they are crushing the crypto currency mining.My computer can't mine any of these.

No one one knows what another coin can get in the market.I looked up on coinsmarketcap recently added coins and found Votecoin which is at is acceptable state (November 2017).All I wanted it to mine some VOT(votecoins) but I really can't get it to work most of the miners are for CUDA 7.5 or 8.0.Although I cannot even get a cpu miner.It uses Equihash algorithm, would be fine for my old system at lease 2 -5 coins a day right now.just think as I think if getting 150 VOT(votecoins) with my current rig and after months or even 1 - 2 years like bitcoin it at least be the worth of 25$.But in this meantime if I mine Monero or Dash I won't be near the revenue I will in an investment like this.People with mining rig's and good Cards get instant results but what about the people who don't have equipment's but can mine and wait for a great revenue

Plz someone just help me out, it will go a long way down.I am at a point now to lose all the hope I got as a crypto currency enthusiast, neither of the software recognizes my GPU but for VOT which is currently 2 cents per coin.All I want is a satisfaction I have some coins in my wallet at his point.Even getting 1 really 1 coin in 10 hrs is enough for my satisfaction now.

Please even a cpu miner is accepted for me.

more specifically,

> How do I mine Votecoins using my Cpu Even

or if you the answer of this

> How do I mine Vote coin with my GPU
>
> Cpu Miner for equihash algorithm

I do not want any answers like it is not profitable.At this stage I am not looking to profit but to satisfy my heart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First show what Algorithm it is built on. Second look where you can see Mining Pools for it (Google can help). Third download Mining Tool.

**Pro tip:** Mining with CPU is less rentable than with GPU and it makes no sensen anymore.